# displaying data in nstableview from a directory

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nsfilemanager

I want to display fileNames , types , size ... in a table view.
I've tried to display the file names.the table view is filled by data but they are not displayed.
A warning is shown : 'directoryContectsAtPath:' is deprecated.
Here is the code (.m file). 
help please

```
@implementation TableController

-(void) awakeFromNib{

    [uploadTable setDataSource:self];

}

-(IBAction)showFiles:(id)sender{
    [fileNames removeAllObjects];
    [fileNames autorelease];
    fileNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[[NSFileManager defaultManager]directoryContentsAtPath:@"/"]retain]];
    [uploadTable reloadData];
}


-(int)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)uploadTable{
    return [fileNames count];
}

-(id)tableWiew:(NSTableView *)uploadTable objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(int)row{

    return [[fileNames objectAtIndex:row] stringValue];
}

@end
```

Comment: Use contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error: instead.  This is very easy to find in the documents -- if you type in the name of a depreciated method and go to that link, it usually says which alternative to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid the deprecation warning, you can use

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath: error:nil]
```

instead of

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager]directoryContentsAtPath:@"/"]
```

Also, you have a typo in method (tableView, not tableWiew)

```
-(id)tableWiew:(NSTableView *)uploadTable objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(int)row
```